# Kayframes não funciona

Tags: html, css, sass

Estou tentando fazer uma pequena animação, onde o ícone de um botão precisa ficar flutuando quando for ativado o hover, porém a animação não ocorre por nada. No entanto a mudança da cor ocorre normalmente, o problema é realmente a animação. Não sei mais o que tentar:

SCSS:

```
     @keyframes translate {
     from {
        transform: translate(0) scale(1);
      }

    to {
      transform: translate(-8px) scale(1.1);
      }
    }


  .header-icons a:hover {
  i {
     color: $red-light;
     animation: translate 0.8s infinite alternate; }
     }
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Tendo em vista que [esta pergunta já foi feita](/q/591171/70) e orientações já foram passadas, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações. Entretanto, pode ser usado na postagem original, após restaurada - da mesma forma, as edições para esclarecimento devem ser feitas na postagem original.